# Lighthouse Audit says, "Links to cross-origin destinations are unsafe" and shows some URL which doesn't exist in my theme. How to fix them?

Tags: wordpress, lighthouse

I was auditing my website using Lighthouse audit by Google. In the portion of "Best Practices", it shows 3 errors, out of them there is one error I want to know more and its solution. This image "https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtNCW.jpg"
is attached. It shows some share URLs (means any share button below the post which we see usually on every website) but my WordPress theme doesn't have any share option in any post. But when I point on each of them they show to go twitter, facebook, pinterest, etc. How can I access these URLs (Add `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noreferrer"` to any external links to improve performance and prevent security vulnerabilities) to rectify my website? Obviously, those websites are not my property. But the URL shows this. How to find this URL on my website and how to rectify this issue by using the recommendation given in this audit.

PS: I am using the theme, "writing". I am not using any plugin which is related to social share.

Comment: Can anyone answer this question? Any expert here?

Comment: have you fixed the errors?